# How can I count affected rows by an insert and a merge statement

Tags: db2, plsql

I have little experience with DB2. I have been trying to find out how to get the number of affected rows (after insert and merge statements) and/or a success message to give back to my HTTP Post request. Can anyone help me on this?

Using [DB2 node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-red-contrib-db2) in Node-RED.

Comment: That certainly depends on what client interface you use to run your statements.

Comment: I am using Node-RED with DB2 nodes.

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with Node+DB2, but if you can wrap the INSERT in a SELECT you can use ["data-change-table-references"](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0059206.html#r0059206__dctr) to SELECT COUNT(*) FROM NEW TABLE(INSERT INTO some-table ...)

Comment: @DaveJones: Please consider reposting your comment as an answer, as it seems to have helped the OP, thanks.

Comment: Is it possible to do something equivalent with a MERGE statement?